# Jquery select options not disabling

Tags: jquery

I have the following function in my jQuery code:

```
function checkUNSelectBox(item){ 
    $('#DELETE option').each(function(){ <!--alert(item);-->
        if ($(this).val() !=item) { 
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            return false;   
        }
    });
}
```

However, only the first item in the list is being disabled instead of all the rest that are not equals to "item". Why is this so?

Comment: could you please set an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Umm.. because you have `return false;`? Just remove that line and more items will be disabled.

Comment: BTW, `$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");` is a long-winded way of saying `this.disabled = true;`

Comment: thanks guys! it was indeed of the false! i've learnt something new today. thank you once again1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't need to `return false` in function you just remove it.

```
 function checkUNSelectBox(item){ 
 {
   $('#DELETE option').each(function(){

  if($(this).val() != item)
  {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  }   

});
```

just check it out in [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vdSX/)

Comment: Setting `$(this).attr('disabled','true');` is not correct. Either `$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');` or `$(this).prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: yeah..i agree with u.i am just give him suggestion for just remove `return false`.

Comment: Then why did you change that line at all? ;)

Comment: bcz u are pointed on it.i always follow as my senior guide :D

Comment: No, I mean it's still not correct :) With `.attr()` you change the HTML attributes. In case of `disabled`, the standard defines that *if* you give it a value, the value must be `"disabled"`, like `<option disabled="disabled">` (yes, that's right, the value `"true"` is not allowed here). With `.prop()` you change the DOM element properties. Here it is a boolean, like `options[0].disabled = true;`. So when you want to use `true` as a value, use jQuery's `.prop()` or just `this.disabled = true;`, which is also faster and less typing.

Comment: finally.i change my mistake.thanks for guide me.i learned something new related this.hands off for your advice.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are returning `false` from the function. That ends the loop of the `each` method.

> "We can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning
>   false."

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

just remove `return false;` you dont want to quit the function if you have found one thats not equal to `item`.

Im not 100% sure but dont´you want to enable the items that equal to item also?

```
function checkUNSelectBox(item){ 
    $('#DELETE option').each(function(){
        this.disabled = (this.value !== item); // true / false
    });
}
```

will enable the options that equal to `item` and disable the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your element id, try to change them to class